# Eclipse CDT indexer cannot resolve includes with a directory name in the include

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have some #includes that have the last directory in the path to the header in the include as follows; #include "libxml/xmlwriter.h"
Where the full path to the header is "usr/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlwriter.h".
The project builds no problem. It's just the Indexer that cannot seem to resolve these files.
Yes, I have specified the include path in all the (seemingly redundant) places that Eclipse allows you to put them in Project Properties.
I've googled this to death and cannot seem to find this exact case. Most hits that come up tell you to set up the path in "Paths and Symbols", "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc...". I have done them all!

I'm running Eclipse Juno and CDT 8.6. (Although this has never worked in any previous versions)

I know I could go through and change the includes in all the places where libxml is used, but this should be a last resort, since GCC has no problems with the current setup.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the debugging steps in the manual? If so, can you provide the scanner information and exactly what you have added to the settings? http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_scanner_discovery.htm?cp=10_2_7_1  For example, you say the full path to the header is "usr/[...]" and I assume that is just a typo, not a relative directory.

Comment: PS Juno? I doubt its related, but maybe time to upgrade, I see you have for CDT, just not Eclipse.

Comment: @Jonah, Sorry I'm using Eclipse Luna. (Just cant get Juno out of my head for some reason).

Comment: @Jonah: Yes, that's a typo. I missed the leading forward slash. 
   As far as 'debugging steps', I'm not sure what you mean there, however I have done everything in the manual link you sent.
   You said to 'provide scanner information'. Do you mean the contents of the .cproject file? All the settings I entered appear to be there.
   
   Thanks,
        Steve

Comment: What I am talking about is the scanner output info, "The output of built-in compiler specs detectors can be inspected to troubleshoot problems running the command. To do so, enable checkbox "Allocate console in the Console View"."

Comment: I attempted to get the scanner console output as in says in the docs. For whatever reason it will not run for the Cross GCC Toolchain setup. It works just fine for the regular GCC Built In. I'm giving up on this minor annoyance. I just can't justify spending any more time on it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need for you to spend more time on it, but if you could answer a few questions so that I can have another go at reproducing. 1- Host platform (linux/win/mac)? 2- Target platform? 3- Stock CDT or vendor provided? I hadn't realized that you were doing a cross compile before. The reason I hadn't is that it seems strange that you are doing a cross compile, but using host header files.

Comment: OK, the host platform is CentOS 5.5 guest VM (on VMware Workstation running on Windows 7). The target is an embedded PC. also running a stripped down version of CentOS 5.5. So initially I simply coded and compiled on the host and downloaded the executable to the embedded device. But once I decided to start using c++11 features I had to build a newer version of GCC (4.8.5). Not wanting to overwrite the original GCC on the host system I installed the new 4.8.5 in /usr/local/... and had to tell Eclipse I was using a Cross compile to get it to look at the desired GCC and libraries.

Comment: Also, it is the stock CDT. I realize that Cross Compile usually means for an Arm processor or whatever. But this was the only thing I could come up with to get Eclipse to cooperate at all.

Comment: I'll have a go at reproducing with the extra info. Not sure if I can add much, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: Problem solved! It just kept knawing at me, and I felt that it had nothing to do with 'Cross GCC Toolchain', so I created a 'canned' Hello World project w/ Linux GCC Toolchain, and added the 'libxml/xmlwriter.h' header and there were no problems. The only thing different between that project and mine is that it only has one 'include path' listed in the Build settings, where my project has several. On a whim, I put that troublesome path at the top of the list in my project and Bam, 'unresolved' problem is gone. Not sure why, but not complaining. Thanks again for your help!